# How to run CommandLineRunner in spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on an application using spring.
I expect its run to be called when the app starts.
But it doesn't seem work even if the code and the setting is both ok.
Here's the code.

```
package mrs;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringJpa2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringJpa2Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package config;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import mrs.model.Comment;
import mrs.repository.CommentRepository;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner{
    private final CommentRepository repository;
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("start");

        //doSomething

        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is Spring scanning your `config` package?  Try adding:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "config" })
```

to your `SpringBootApplication` annotation.